# How to pass data between 2 different pages using jQuery POST method?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have 2 php files named card_process.php and payment.php. I'm trying to pass data from the cart_process page to payment page. The code goes like this:

cart_process.php:

```
$paynow = "<button type='submit' id='reset' class='btn btn-danger' align='center' disabled>PAY NOW</button> ";

$cart_box_total = '<div class="cart-products-total" id="cart-products-total" name="subtotalsub">.$total.</div>';

?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reset").click(function() {
        var content = $('#cart-products-total').html();
            $.post("payment.php", { html: content})
            .done(function(data) {
            window.location = "payment.php";
            });
        });
});
</script>
```

And on payment.php:

```
<?php echo $_POST['html']; ?>
```

As the page redirects to `payment.php`, the `$_POST['html']` doesn't echoes anything, but if I use `alert(content)` in cart_process.php it alerts me with the needed data.

How can I post the whole data to the page?

Comment: You're sending the post to page, which returns the results, and then visiting the page on a separate call.

Comment: You cannot mix ajax and a redirect like that ... each is an independent request ... one a POST, the other a GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `window.location = "payment.php";` with:

```
$('body').append( data );
```

See how that works out. Eventually you may want to designate a destination target element:

```
<div id="ajax-target"></div>
```

Then instead of `$('body').append( data )` you would have:

```
$('#ajax-target').html( data );
```

**UPDATE**

If you must be redirected, then you do not need ajax. Here is how you can do that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reset").click(function() {
       var content = $('#cart-products-total').html();
       $('<form action="payments.php" method="POST"/>')
       .html( '<textarea name="html">' + content + '</textarea>' )
       [0].submit();
     });
});
```

Comment: after editing the code it doesn't redirects me to payment.php

Comment: Either you use ajax or you use default form submission with redirection. You cannot do both -- see my comment under the question.

Comment: I want to use ajax to post the { html: content} to payment.php, after the script ends I want the user to be redirected to payment.php and the { html: content} should be echoed at that page

Comment: I repeat .. you cannot do both. Choose one please.

Answer (score 0):

You have some misconceptions of the order of operations taking place here.  You're actually invoking `payment.php` *twice*.  Once as a POST request with the `html` parameter here:

```
$.post("payment.php", { html: content})
```

and then *again* as a GET request without any parameter here:

```
window.location = "http://selina.co.il/payment.php";
```

The client-side code is essentially ignoring the result of the POST request and just sending the user to the GET request, which naturally doesn't `echo` anything.

---

It's not entirely clear what you're *trying* to do here, but if you're using AJAX then you probably don't really want to be redirecting the user to anything anyway.  So instead of doing this:

```
window.location = "http://selina.co.il/payment.php";
```

Do something in that AJAX callback to modify the *current* page.  Maybe set the `data` variable to some content on the page?  Something like this?:

```
$('#someDiv').html(data);
```

It's really up to you what *should* happen here, we can't tell for certain from the code posted.

---

If the flow of the application indeed *is* that the user should be redirected to another page, then you have two options:

**1:** Expect a GET parameter instead of a POST parameter in the PHP code and include it on the redirect:

```
window.location = "http://selina.co.il/payment.php?html=" + encodeURIComponent(content);
```

That will *probably* be pretty ugly if `content` is what it implies to be.

**2:** Don't use AJAX at all and simply have a `form` which POSTS to `payment.php`.

Comment: I am trying to pass the $.post("payment.php", { html: content}) to payment.php page, after the post succes redirect the user to payment.php. the GET method is bad for me is there a way I can redirect the user and echo the POST result at payment.php?

I cannot use the form since im trying to POST a div

Comment: @Svidlak: A redirect itself is by design a GET request, it can't be a POST.  And I think you're still misunderstanding the nature of multiple requests being entirely separate and stateless.  One thing you could do is use a normal `form` and use jQuery to capture its `submit` event.  In that event, set the `contents` to a hidden form value.  Then allow the form submit to continue as normal.